# I am trying to upgrade PHP on Uwamp. But somehow if I want to run the upgrade php.7.3.3 and or php 8.3.3 Apache stops. php 7.2.7 works fine

Tags: php, apache, upgrade

Can any body please assist me. I am trying to upgrade PHP on my Uwamp to php 7.4.33 and or php 8.3.3 But somehow if I want to run the upgrade php.7.3.3 and or php 8.3.3 Apache stops running. php 7.2.7 works fine on my uwamp. I need to upgrade to a higher versions due to a theme I want to use that do not run on php 7.2.7

I have installed the php versions directly in the uwamp C:\UwAmp\bin\php folder and started uwamp. uwamp have picked up the new versions of php and it installed it. no problem, but it does not want to run the Apache. also under the php installation tab "uwamp php repository" the new php versions does not show.
I have also tried to install the php version directly onto windows via edit system environment with no joy
I have also configured uwamp "httpd_uwamp.conf" with no joy
There is not many uwamp tutorials on youtube. I found plenty of tuorials on wamp and xwamp, but only a few on uwamp that does not help with my problem

Comment: Can you provide more information such as any errors you're receiving or commands you've used?